# Non-ascii characters from json to postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

**A python, Postgres novice here**

this is my JSON entry, "data".
I want the same to insert into my Postgres DB

```
{"address": "Avinguda de España 68"}
```

using python

```
address = json.dumps(data["address"])
```

tried:

`address = json.dumps(dic["address"], ensure_ascii=False)` as well.

Both of these statements gave the same result as following

(getting this in Postgres)

```
Avinguda de EspaÃ±a 68
```

[postgres entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIbfL.png)

What am I doing wrong? or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the field type in Postgres? What is the encoding for the database?

Comment: it all depends on the encoding of your db. Which one are you using?

Comment: What is your client encoding and your database encoding? How is the string encoded on the client side? How does the value in the database look when you cast it to `bytea`?

Comment: db encoding UTF8;  postgress field type TEXT;   
`json.dumps(dic["address"], ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')` - gave me this: `Avinguda de Espa\xc3\x83\xc2\xb1a 68` . how do I check client encoding?

Comment: To see encoding in `psql` do `\l db_name`.